# Loop data with date as maine heading

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and I just developed a code looking at some tutorials.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'db_connect.php';

$query  = "SELECT id, date, ip, website FROM response";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$dateArray=array();


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)  or die (mysql_error()))
{
echo "Date :{$row['date']} <br>" .
     "IP : {$row['ip']} <br>" .
     "Url : {$row['website']} <br><br>";
}

?>
```

This displays record in this format

```
Date :2012-11-23 17:07:57
IP : 198.169.127.145
Url : 2webdesign.com

Date :2012-11-25 21:45:11
IP : 198.169.127.145
Url : 2webdesign.com

Date :2012-11-25 21:45:51
IP : 198.169.127.145
Url : www.sarcan.ca
```

I want to display records where date is on top and data is displayed under date

For instance

```
Date: 25 November 2012
Url 
IP

URl
IP

Date 26 Nov 2012
URL
IP

URL
IP
```

Secondly I also want to have an option to export this to Excelsheet.

Can anybody have a look at the code and help me out.

I know this is very basic code as I just have a basic idea oh php

Comment: Your tutorial is outdated! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I would suggest that you avoid using the mysql_ functions as they are no longer being developed. You should be moving toward PDO MySQL or MySQLi.

Comment: if the date is common the data should be displayed under 1 date

Comment: remove the or die() bit from your fetch call. it should be on the mysql_query line. you're likely to dump false errors everytime you run out of rows to fetch.

Comment: Please use `<br />` as `<br>` is not XML/XHTML compliant.

Comment: thanks njk and marc. I ll do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please keep in mind all the comments to your original post, because they are all valid. Here is a possible solution (untested, so may need light modification) to the first part of your question:

```
<?php
$query  = "SELECT DATE(date) as date, id, date as fulldate, ip, website FROM response ORDER BY date";

// do query...

$previousDate = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // check to see if the previous date is different to this date
    if($previousDate != $row['date']) { // date is different; start a new heading
    ?>
<div>Date :<?php echo $row['date']; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
<ul>
   <li>IP :<?php echo $row['ip']; ?></li>
   <li>Url :<?php echo $row['website']; ?></li>
</ul>
<?php 
    // assign current date to the $previousDate variable.
    $previousDate = $row['date'];
} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot gareth L. There were some minor errors which I solved and  you helped me in reloving my first question.

Comment: How Is it possible to use table instead of div and ul li.